# React beautiful DND - I get "Unable to find draggable with id: 1"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

In the code below the UI renders two "Column" components and each column contains two draggable elements called "Tasks". When the user drags a "Task" between columns the code works - *up to a point*. When the user continuously drags the task components around eventually they will stop dragging and the user gets an error that says:

> Unable to find draggable with id: X

I don't know why this happens nor how to fix it.

**Note:** I am assuming the way the library works is when you drag elements you need to reorder and update your state in the `onDragEnd` function.

Here is my code:

**app.js**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {DragDropContext} from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import helper from './helper_functions'

import Column from './Components/Column';

function App() {

  let initialState =   [
    {
      groupName:"Today",
      tasks:[
          {id:"1", title:"Test-1"},
          {id:"2", title:"Test-2"}
        ]
    },
    {
      groupName:"Tomorrow", 
      tasks:[
          {id:"3", title:"Test-3"},
          {id:"4", title:"Test-4"}
        ]
    },
  ]


  const [taskList, setTasks] = useState(initialState)

  function onDragEnd(val){

     let result = helper.reorder(val.source,val.destination,taskList);
     setTasks(result)
  }

  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
       <Column droppableId="Today" list= {taskList[0].tasks} type="TASK"/>
       <Column droppableId ="Tomorrow" list = {taskList[1].tasks} type="TASK"/>
       <div> context hello world </div>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**src/helper_functions**

```
export default {
    reorder:function(source,destination,taskDataArr){

     let taskData = [...taskDataArr]

 //     //_____________________________________________________________Source data
    let sourceGroupIndex = taskData.findIndex((val, index) => {                // iterate and find "Today" (or other) index in list data
        return val.groupName === source.droppableId
    });

    let draggedTask = taskData[sourceGroupIndex].tasks.find((val, index) => {  // Get specific task object based on index
        return source.index === index
    }); // dragged object

    let sourceListCopyWithElementRemoved = taskData[sourceGroupIndex].tasks.filter((val, index) => {
        return index !== source.index // removes dragged element from array
    });

    // //__________________________________________________________________Destination data

    let destinationGroupIndex = taskData.findIndex((val, index) => {  // iterate and find "Tomorrow" (or other) index in list data
        return val.groupName === destination.droppableId
    });


    taskData[destinationGroupIndex].tasks.splice(destination.index, 0, draggedTask); // insert dragged item to new place
    taskData[sourceGroupIndex].tasks = sourceListCopyWithElementRemoved

    return taskData

  }


}
```

**src/Components/Column**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Droppable} from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import Task from "../../Components/Task"

function Column(props){
   const { classes, droppableId, list, type} = props;

   let style = {
    backgroundColor:"orange",
    height:"300px",
    width:"400px",
    margin:"100px"

   }

   console.log(list)



    return (

       <Droppable droppableId = {droppableId} type={type}>
       {provided => (

          <div {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef} style={style}>
          <h2>{droppableId}</h2>

            {list.map((val,index)=>{
               return <Task id={val.id} key={index} index={index} title={val.title}/>
            })}

           {provided.placeholder}
          </div>
        )
       }
       </Droppable>
    )
}

export default Column
```

**src/Components/Task**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Draggable} from 'react-beautiful-dnd';



function Task(props){
    const { classes, id, index,title } = props;
    let style = {
    backgroundColor:"red",


   }

    return (
       <Draggable draggableId ={id} index={index} type="TASK">

         {(provided) => (
            <div
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.draggableProps}
              {...provided.dragHandleProps}
            >
              <h4 style={style}>{title}</h4>
            </div>
        )}

       </Draggable>
    )
}

export default Task
```

Comment: Dear bro @William, For such a case like your question. it is better to put a reproduction of your project on GitHub or GitLab and leave its link here, someone like me checks out the project and finds the bug. Literally, I ask you this.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the polite response. I'll do that after work.

Comment: @William can you provide some fiddle for this?

Comment: Looks like someone below created a codesandbox

Answer (score 83, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. Error `Unable to find draggable with id: X`

In the `Column` component you used `index` as a key for the tasks. I think this is [what causes this error](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1673#issuecomment-571293508).

#### Using the task `id` as `key`, in `Column`, makes this error go away.

2. `reorder` has some issues:

   - it removes a task when dropped in the same column
   - raises an error when a task is dropped outside the columns

I had a bit of fun with you code and [tried another way to reorder](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-experiment-4k722?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). This way of reordering might come in handy if you ever add a more columns - there is still room for improvements.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Using `ID` that is the same for `draggableId` `prop` instead of `index` for `key` prop solved my problem

Comment: @SyedAqeel Thanks, man!! sometimes comments are better than answers.

Comment: I had `key` as `index` instead of `id` - thank you ;-)

Answer (score 84):

If you are getting this error on React 18

```
Unable to find draggable with id:
```

Try removing StrictMode

Comment: why the strict mode is affect this behavior ?

Comment: Seconded. This works for me, but I'd like to keep strict mode-- what's happening here?

Comment: there is drop-in replacement that fixed this issue here:
https://github.com/hello-pangea/dnd

Comment: Rather than replace the whole library or turn off Strict Mode, try using this solution: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/2350#issuecomment-1318179729

Comment: @MarcinHubert I believe that fork is a good enough solution that it warrants it's own answer. I would upvote it if it were.

Comment: this code helped me to solve a problem:
https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/2399#issuecomment-1175638194

Comment: Wow. This solved my problem as well. I am on Next 13

Comment: I'm using `hello-pangea/dnd` and the problem still happens, don't know if it's my faut. Edit: was my fault, I forgot to add the `key` to my `Draggable` , now the everything works fine.

Answer (score 16):

Not for this case, but
For every one - check `provided.draggableProps` not `provided.dropableProps`

```
 <Draggable draggableId ={id} index={index} type="TASK">

         {(provided) => (
            <div
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.draggableProps}
              {...provided.dragHandleProps}
            >
              <h4 style={style}>{title}</h4>
            </div>
        )}
</Draggable>
```

RBD try find node by provided.draggableProps. Missing this props got error: `Unable to find draggable with id: X`

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue, I was mapping through multiple draggable and had missed the key prop,
Adding the key to Draggable fixed the issue for me

```
{tasks.map((t, index) => (
  <Draggable
    draggableId={t._id}
    index={index}
    key={t._id} >
     ....
  </Draggable>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added `key={task.id}` for my `Draggable` wrapper and also added `key={column.id}` to my `Droppable` wrapper and it works out of the box!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. Just pass your id instead of the index and the issue will be fixed

Comment: @AgostinhoNeto solution works for me ,the issue was with droppable key , Thanks

Answer (score 13):

**For Error:**

> Unable to find draggable with id: X

1. Remove Strict mode in React js.
2. If you are using Next.js you can find the strict mode in `next.config.js` file

**For Error:**

> Invariant failed: Draggable[id: 1]: Unable to find drag handle do the following

```
{process.browser && (
        <section>
          <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
                     //Your code with droppable and draggable
           </DragDropContext>
        </section>
)}
```

[Related issue](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1756#issuecomment-1159334259)

Comment: It worked but now I am getting hydration error in Next.js

Answer (score 8):

Removing <React.StrictMode> fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue however the following steps helps me

**Step 1:**

```
draggableId should be string, not an integer
```

as per https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1512

**Step 2:**

if you are coming from EggHead tutorial, this might have missed.
Try to add a key property as mentioned in the top answer

```
<Draggable key={item.id} draggableId={item.id.toString()} index={index} >
```

Answer (score 5):

If you still getting this issue, there was a simple solution for you. Just remove `<React.StrictMode>` from the `index.js`.

Answer (score 5):

The library is not being maintained any longer. I switch to the fork:

https://github.com/hello-pangea/dnd

And all issues were resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Was tearing my hair out trying to get the unmaintained version to work!

Comment: All the tutorials worked perfectly in a sandbox but failed miserably on my local machine. Your tip saved me. Thanks a lot for this

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a solution

- Without removing Strict Mode
- Without replacing the whole `react-beautiful-dnd` library

#### 1. Create this `StrictModeDroppable` component in your project:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Droppable, DroppableProps } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

export const StrictModeDroppable = ({ children, ...props }: DroppableProps) => {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const animation = requestAnimationFrame(() => setEnabled(true));

    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(animation);
      setEnabled(false);
    };
  }, []);

  if (!enabled) {
    return null;
  }

  return <Droppable {...props}>{children}</Droppable>;
};
```

#### 2. Then replace `<Droppable>` components in your project with `<StrictModeDroppable>`.

It should work!

---

Source: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/2399#issuecomment-1175638194

Comment: This should be the top answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the integer value to a string. It'll solve the issue as it solved mine

```
{tasks.map((t, index) => (
  <Draggable
    draggableId={t._id.toString()}
    index={index}
    key={t._id} >
     ....
  </Draggable>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a YouTube lesson on react-beautiful-dnd. He posted his
   lesson progress in the Code Sandbox [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa3Nfd1VHZXJYd183QVNWR05paFByaUVydlZRUXxBQ3Jtc0tud3VjUVlxeFlYb182N0U2SUR0RjhpdG1PY3h6akt4OXpFbmk0aGwxY09zVW9vbHo2ejRBU0hiaWllUEJENmlXcU5YeFZnUkYwdGQ0QmYxWW5mdFdGMmtxWlZEalc0RDFtWWpOeDRVaVZfMHhEc2MyOA&q=https%3A%2F%2Fcodesandbox.io%2Fs%2Fjovial-leakey-i0ex5&v=Vqa9NMzF3wc)
   You can open it and make sure. But I have on "react": "^18.1.0" does
   not work and gives an error

   > Unable to find draggable with id:X

   And on older versions of react everything also works without
   errors.Try for example another version of react"^17.0.2"ю It worked
   for me
2. Also remember, when installing the react-beautiful-dnd library, were there any dependency conflicts? Maybe you have not established all the connections and because of this it does not work correctly. In any case, as a test, I suggest downloading the code from the lesson and checking in my project whether it works or not. If it works, it means an error in the code, if not, then react-beautiful-dvd does not work correctly

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help someone. If you are experiencing this even your code is correct. Please check your react version. In react version 18.0, dnd will show unable to find draggable with id warning. Current solution to downgrade to 17 and it works flawlessly. I searched for the solution like remove strict mode, using dynamic import and other things but currently it's related to react 18.

Answer (score 1):

It works with react-beautiful-dnd and React 18 in StrictMode.
https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/2399#issuecomment-1175638194

Answer (score 0):

Post it here, since this is the top link the Google for the same error.

It might be the case, that you do not render an element with the `provided.dragHandleProps`

```
<div>
      {someCondition && (
           <div>
               <DragIndicatorIcon {...provided.dragHandleProps}/>
           </div>
      )}
</div>
```

In this case move `{...provided.dragHandleProps}` outside the condition

```
<div {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
      {someCondition && (
           <div>
               <DragIndicatorIcon {...provided.dragHandleProps}/>
           </div>
      )}
</div>
```

Found this solution [here](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1756#issuecomment-780340335)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by converting draggableId into string

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are experiencing the same problem with the @hello-pangea/dnd library,
converting the id to string worked for me.

```
<Draggable key={ticket.id} draggableId={ticket.id.toString()} index={index}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have provided - draggableId, key and ref

Answer (score 0):

To mirror @MarcinHubert's comment in one of the answers, Atlassian no longer maintains this repo, and there is a drop-in replacement that is being actively maintained that fixes this problem: https://github.com/hello-pangea/dnd

Comment: In my case, even using this lib, the error was present, but it was my fault. I basically forgot to add `key` attribute to the `Droppable`, only the `Draggable` had the key, now both have, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I actually faced the same issue but the above solution worked for me. I was using Next.js 14 and typescript:

```js
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Droppable, DroppableProps } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

export const StrictModeDroppable = ({ children, ...props }: DroppableProps) => {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const animation = requestAnimationFrame(() => setEnabled(true));

    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(animation);
      setEnabled(false);
    };
  }, []);

  if (!enabled) {
    return null;
  }

  return <Droppable {...props}>{children}</Droppable>;
};



<DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
      <StrictModeDroppable droppableId="items">
        {(provided) => (
          <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
            {stateItems.map((item, index) => (
              <ListItem key={index} id={index.toString()} index={index}>
                {item}
              </ListItem>
            ))}
            {provided.placeholder}
          </div>
        )}
      </StrictModeDroppable>
    </DragDropContext>
```